# mysql query group by/order by count

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is a table:

```
ID    Item  status  updatetime   author
1     a     1       2014-01-02   Mike
2     a     1       2014-02-01   Jack
3     b     2       2014-01-10   John
4     b     1       2014-10-10   Ben
5     b     2       2014-01-11   Sam
6     c     3       2014-01-02   Aron
7     c     1       2014-11-01   Aron
8     c     1       2014-10-20   Max
9     d     3       2014-10-20   Mike
```

I would like to count the total number of each status for each Item, and the latest date/author of the items

The result should be like this:

count(status) =2 when item=a and status=1

count(status) =0 when item=a and status=2

count(status) =0 when item=a and status=3

```
Item    status_1    status_2    status_3    Latestupdate    author
a        2            0           0         2014-02-01       Jack
b        1            2           0         2014-10-10       Ben
c        2            0           1         2014-11-01       Aron
d        0            0           1         2014-10-20       Mike
```

How to write the sql ？

Comment: Do you really need that sort of pivot?  DO you only expect a certain number of status values that will always be known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a pivot along with some other information.  I would suggest this approach:

```
select item,
       sum(status = 1) as status_1,
       sum(status = 2) as status_2,
       sum(status = 3) as status_3,
       max(updatetime) as LatestUpdate,
       substring_index(group_concat(author order by updatetime desc), ',', 1) as author
from table t
group by item;
```

The tricky part is the last column, `author`.  This uses a trick to get the author for the last update.  The trick is to concatenate all the authors together, ordered by the update time.  Then choose the first element of the list.